# Obtener fecha,dia de la semana, mes y año en php

Tags: php, javascript, html

Necesito obtener una fecha con estos datos:

```
Viernes 14 de Julio del 2017
```

Solo que cambie la parte de "Viernes" por el nombre del día actual(Lunes/martes/...etc), "14" por el número del día actual, "Julio" por el mes actual y "2017" por el año actual.

Comment: Hola Aristeas. No preguntes algo tan amplio. Has de mostrar lo que has intentado para que podamos ayudarte. Si tienes dudas conctretas, pregunta aqui.  Un saludo

Comment: Lo quieres hacer con php o con javascript? especifica

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solución en PHP:

Debes hacerlo de esta manera para mostrar la fecha larga

```
<?php
 echo date('l, d M Y');

//Formato de salida: Friday, 16 Aug 2017
 ?>
```

Ahora, si la quieres en español entonces haz lo siguiente:

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_ALL,"es_ES");

echo strftime("%A %d de %B del %Y"); // esta funcion formatea una fecha/hora local según la configuración regional que manejemos con setlocale

//Salida: miercoles 16 de agosto del 2017
?>
```

Donde:

**LC_ALL:** Es una constante que especifica la categoría de las funciones afectadas por la configuración regional, en este caso toma en cuanta todas las constantes.

**es_ES:**  Los primeros 2 caracteres identifican al idioma, los 2 últimos al país.

Comment: Ya que preguntaste al usuario para que eligiera PHP o JS, pudiste esperar a que te contestara o al menos dar las dos soluciones no? ^^' Esperemos que sea PHP lo que necesite o le valga. Un saludo

Comment: Yo le di esta solución porque de la manera en que lo pregunta se puede asumir que al usuario le sirve cualquiera de las dos formas. No obstante, le pregunté porque no lo dejó claro y estoy en espera de su respuesta, y si es con javascript edito mi respuesta para que le sea útil. Saludos

Comment: Perfecto pues, gracias

Comment: En mi caso no me trae el setlocale(LC_ALL,"es_ES"); en español, tuve que cambiar el segundo parametro como vacio  o nulo 
 de esta forma  setlocale(LC_ALL,NULL);  uso windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la función de PHP `strftime` la cual te devuelve el Formato de fecha y hora locales de acuerdo con la configuración regional. La podrías usar de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
  setlocale(LC_ALL,"es_ES"); // setlocate Establecer la información del localismo (región)
  echo strftime("%A %d de %B del %Y"); //asignas el formato
?>
```

y se mostrará de la siguiente manera:

```
miércoles 16 de agosto del 2017
```

Comment: Soldier, gracias por tu respuesta. Recuerda dar tiempo al autor para que edite la pregunta y que añada lo que ha intentado. Asi no se promueve las preguntas sin esfuerzo *aparente*. Un saludo